# Fitting a image with text underneath inside a fixed div size

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

My question I would imagine is solved by some basic css, however I cannot seem to make it work. I simply have an  larger image with text underneath. I want them to fit/scale into a fixed size of a div with a border, however I want it to be responsive in the way that I can change the div size, and it will still adjust appropriately. My problem is that the image pushes the text outside of my border div. Any help? I have a JSFiddle with a random google image for example, you can edit and repost if you'd like. Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/ehuwg7w2/1/

```
<div class="a">
    <img src="https://kremalicious.com/media/gen/Free-Monkey-Breath-Not-Soylent-Green-800by1200-47ce3e.jpg">
    <p>I want to be inside the div height, not outside!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: .a {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.a img { max-width: 100%;
}

Comment: change this to height:100% as above comment

Comment: Using height: auto or 100% of course does keep the text within the div. However, what if I needed the specific height as a certain pixel, like the example 500px. I know the height: auto works perfect, but only if your div is not a set height. I'm looking to scale the image based on size of the div to allow the text to show appropriately. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You don't want to fix the height of `div.a` you can only use `height:100%;` instead of `height:500px;`

```css
.a {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.a img { max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <img src="https://kremalicious.com/media/gen/Free-Monkey-Breath-Not-Soylent-Green-800by1200-47ce3e.jpg">
    <p>I want to be inside the div height, not outside!</p>
</div>
```

But if you need `div.a` to have fixed `height` and want to fit the image and the text inside its height, you can do it like this:

```css
.a {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  display:table;
}

.a img { 
  width: 100%;
  display:table-row;
  height:100%;
}
.a p{
  display:table-row;
  height:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <img src="https://kremalicious.com/media/gen/Free-Monkey-Breath-Not-Soylent-Green-800by1200-47ce3e.jpg">
    <p>I want to be inside the div height, not outside!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The table method seems to be the closest to what I was looking for because I was needed for a specific div height, without using auto. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
.a {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.a img { max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```css
.a {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.a img { 
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <img src="https://kremalicious.com/media/gen/Free-Monkey-Breath-Not-Soylent-Green-800by1200-47ce3e.jpg">
    <p>I want to be inside the div height, not outside!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just set height to 100% instead 500px

```css
.a {
  width: 400px;
  height:100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.a img { max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your `parent div height` to `auto` i.e `.a height`. Thus this automatically take your `div` and `text` inside of your div border.

```css
.a {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;/*Changed this to auto*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.a img { max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <img src="https://kremalicious.com/media/gen/Free-Monkey-Breath-Not-Soylent-Green-800by1200-47ce3e.jpg">
    <p>I want to be inside the div height, not outside!</p>
</div>
```